# GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, magento2.2, gtid

My Magento version is 2.2.3. We are using a Google Cloud SQL 2nd gen instance.

Facing error while run indexing command

> General error: 1787 Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE
>   TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside
>   transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a
>   function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered
>   to be multi-statement transactions., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
>   IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` LIKE
>   `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`

Comment: "That is Magento bug, Already I have reported when Magento 2.1.7 launched. But still, the issue persists." So why post it here? Looks like you are going to need to wait until magento fixes that problem.

Comment: I need to fix it anyhow. I am looking for help

Comment: It looks like the issue @RaymondNijland submitted is [15209](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15209). I believe it is a duplicate of [12124](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12124) which has a bit more traction.

Comment: @logan I got work around and I Have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @PrashantValanda: That's great! Would you be able to post your answer?

Comment: @PrashantValanda can you provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Following the issues posted in [Magento 2 Issue Tracker](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12124), I was able to get rid of this error by disabling binary logging with the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --no-enable-bin-log
```

---

You can also disable binary logging from the web console while creating a Cloud SQL instance:

```
1. Expand "Show Configuration Options"
2. Expand "Enable auto backups and high availability"
3. Uncheck "Enable binary logging"
```

This means that you cannot currently implement a high availability MySQL instance (with Google Cloud SQL) using Magento 2 community edition.

You can track the status of [issue 12124](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12124) for updates.